Voice Chat Suggestion
Krazer and I were dicussing in chat today the most important aspects of language learning.
We both agreed that while chat/QA/learning characters is important, it's the ability to speak that will take you the furthest and make you most valuable. 
The only way to get better at speaking is to practice speaking.
That being said, would it be possible to add in "voice chat" not only to Chinese, but to all language learning subsites on SE?
This would add a unique aspect to SE languages and become more attractive for those learning language.

perhaps if someone has a ventrilo or mumble server, we could host a weekly or monthly conversational bit?

You could all also do Google Plus, if you're so inclined.

Not sure about the chances to add this natively, but hosting an "external" event, like @Krazer suggested, is nice... :D

@Aarthi I forgot about that. G+ would make things a lot easier.

I'd be in for a Google+ chat if anyone wants to try it.

Good suggestion! But Google+ is blocked here. Could ther be some convenient ways?

@Huang I was going to say something about the Great Firewall of China. Ventrilo or Teamspeak are probably the best ways to go.
